# Labels or keys of tcbtheorems in a section

Tags: tcolorbox, indexing, nameref, showlabels, showkeys

I'm sure a lot of people asked this already, but I'm not able to find the correct answer.

I want to keep track of my label/keys that I was giving a tcbtheorem. I don't know the best practise to encounter this problem I would like to have a section or chapter somewhere in my document but I would be also happy with the label/key in the margin section of the pdf.

I saw the idea, that is good to have the label/key in the margin section of the pdf.

But when I tried to solve like that I did get the expected result when I used \label{} (see the provided code below)

Also

```latex
% Command to automatically display the reference
\newcommand{\autoNameref}[1]{\nameref{def:#1}}

\begin{document}
\tcblistof[\section*]{def}{List of Defenition}
```

works fine.

But I can't see the given references of def:Pi or def:TestRef in the margin section or somewhere else.
If I \label it like that:

```latex
{for example Pi\label{def:Pi2}}
```

This goes the wrong direction I would say, why I should \label everything when I did all the previus effort.

Maybe I have to

```latex
\usepackage{nameref} 
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{showexpl}
```

start this in a different way but I don't find any information about that.
I also searched a lot of time in the tcolorbox - manual:
[tcolorbox - manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/tcolorbox.pdf/0)

I would appreciate any hints or solutions.

Thank you for your help.

I tried to shorten my preamble as much I was sure it would be ok.

The following code:

[image: should resolve in this PDF]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nameref} 
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{showexpl}
% Math packages + Access additional mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,mathtools}

% Hyperlinks and PDF properties
\usepackage{hyperref,theoremref}

% Colored boxes and tcolorbox configurations
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}   
% Libraries for diagrams and plots
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{
    % tcolorbox some boxes
    arrows,
    calc,
    shadows.blur}

% Conditional commands
\usepackage{xparse}
% Dummy text generator
\usepackage{lipsum}  % For generating placeholder text
% store a big set of sentences
\unpacklipsum[1-100]

\ExplSyntaxOn
% unpack \lipsumexp
\seq_new:N \g_lipsum_sentences_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\seq_gset_split:NnV \g_lipsum_sentences_seq {.~} \lipsumexp

\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentence}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}O{1-7}}
 {
  \lipsumsentenceaux #1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumsentenceaux}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { #1 }.~
   }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \g_lipsum_sentences_seq { ##1 }.~
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\tcbset{
    BandarolGroundStyle/.style={
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
        varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
        boxed title style={frame code={
            \path[fill=tcbcolback]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
            ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
            arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
            \path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black,right color=tcbcolback!60!black,
                middle color=tcbcolback!80!black]
            ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
            [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
            -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
            [sharp corners]-- cycle;
            }
        ,interior engine=empty
        },
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        label separator=:
        },
    defstyle/.style={
        enhanced,
        before skip=2mm,
        after skip=2mm, 
        colback= #1!5,
        colframe= #1!80!black,
        colbacktitle= #1!75!black,
        boxrule=0.5mm,
        BandarolGroundStyle
    }
}

%================================
% DEFINITION BANDAROLLED THEOREMS
%================================
% list inside={def} maybe a good idea but check it later
% \tcblistof[\section*]{def}{List of Defenition}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section, list inside={def}]{Definition}{Definition}{defstyle=red, title={#2},#1}{def}

%================================
% xparse commands for theorems:
%================================
% reason:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48355/latex-command-with-optional-arguments
% It is also possible to use optional Arguments:
% r = required Argument
% o = optional Argument
% O = optional Argument if empty default value

% Order of the Attributes (Ref, Titel, Body)
% not working because of \MainAttributes in command...
% \newcommand\MainAttributes{O +m +m}
% Order so it is correct with the newtcbtheorem initialisation
% not working because of \MainOrder in command...
% \edef\MainOrder{\{\#2\}\{\#1\}\#3}
% solutions:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551429/how-to-use-newdocumentcommand
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/you-cant-use-macro-parameter-character-in-restricted-horizontal-mode
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393622/using-key-values-in-newdocumentcommand

% to less time maybe a revisit later...

%================================
% DEFINITION BANDAROLLED THEOREMS
%================================

\NewDocumentCommand {\dfn} {O +m +m}{
\begin{Definition}{#2}{#1}#3
\end{Definition}}



% Customize the format for displaying keys and labels
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{\normalfont\small\ttfamily#1}


% Command to automatically display the reference
\newcommand{\autoNameref}[1]{\nameref{def:#1}}

\begin{document}
\tcblistof[\section*]{def}{List of Defenition}
\label{test}
\lipsum[1]

\dfn[Pi]{A defined Number }{for example Pi}

\lipsum[2]

\nameref{def:Pi} \ref{def:Pi}

\begin{LTXexample}[pos=r, width=0.5\linewidth]
\dfn[TestRef]{RefTest}{TextRefTest}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the label is there, but it is hidden behind the title of the tcolorbox as for some reason showkeys uses a `\rlap`. You can move it into the margin:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}   

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section, list inside={def}]
 {Definition}{Definition}{
 frame empty,coltitle=red, %to remove the background
 title={#2},#1}{def}


\begin{document}
\section{A}\label{test}
\section{B}\label{longertest}

\begin{Definition}{A defined Number }{Pi}
for example Pi
\end{Definition}

\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]
 {% 
   \normalfont\small\ttfamily
   \llap{\fbox{#1}\hspace{\marginparsep}}%
 }

\begin{Definition}{A defined Number }{ratio}
for example the golden ratio
\end{Definition}


\ref{test}, \ref{def:Pi} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my mental health.  ;) I upvoted your answer, but my reputation is to low.